# How can I solve this problem with MikTex?

Tags: miktex

this is my first time using LaTex. I installed the basic-miktex-20.11-x64 and the basic-miktex-21.2-x64(latest version), in both cases I got the same error. I tried with two different editors and the error was the same:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2021-04-13 19:33:48,695+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-04-13 19:33:48,695+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-04-13 19:33:48,695+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:715
2021-04-13 19:33:48,695+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-04-13 19:33:48,696+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-04-13 19:33:48,696+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-04-13 19:33:48,696+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 715
2021-04-13 19:33:48,696+0100 INFO  pdflatex - this process (5184) finishes with exit code 1
2021-04-13 19:33:48,699+0100 FATAL pdflatex - major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.
```

In the  C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\makefmt\pdflatex this is  in the file:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: File 'UnicodeData.txt' not found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.28153   }
           
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I tried to update the package database of the Unicode-data but I got the error: Transferred a partial file

Comment: What are the contents of that `initexmf.log`?  If it's long, you'll probably want to pay special attention to the last (bottom) lines of the file.

Comment: find the folder `... \miktex\log\makefmt\pdflatex` (it is probably in `...\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9` but this depends on your installation). There should be a log file in it, show its contents (if there are more than one show the newest).

Comment: I edited the question adding what is in the file. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Why on earth does one always have to ask for a file twice? Find the logs in `log\makefmt\pdflatex`. They tell you why the format creation failed, not the initexmf.log.

Comment: well if unicode-data can't be found then the format can't be created. Try again if you can install the package and if it still fails open and issue at the miktex github.