# Fatal error in pdflatex; The memory dump file could not be found

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, miktex-update

After a fresh MikTeX install on a new Windows 10 Enterprise machine, I cannot compile even the simplest file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    Hello world!
\end{document}
```

The first time the error is that I haven't updated, I then checked for updates (2nd run), and then updated (3rd run). These three runs produce the log:

```
2021-08-19 17:27:12,792+0300 INFO  pdflatex - this process (4428) started by 'cmd' with command line: C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe sample.tex
2021-08-19 17:27:12,808+0300 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2021-08-19 17:27:12,900+0300 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2021-08-19 17:27:12,971+0300 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2021-08-19 17:27:14,907+0300 ERROR pdflatex - C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2021-08-19 17:27:14,907+0300 ERROR pdflatex - output:
2021-08-19 17:27:14,907+0300 ERROR pdflatex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2021-08-19 17:27:14,907+0300 FATAL pdflatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-08-19 17:27:14,907+0300 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-08-19 17:27:14,908+0300 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:717
2021-08-19 17:27:14,908+0300 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-08-19 17:27:14,908+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-08-19 17:27:14,908+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-08-19 17:27:14,908+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 717
2021-08-19 17:27:14,914+0300 INFO  pdflatex - this process (4428) finishes with exit code 1
2021-08-19 17:27:14,916+0300 FATAL pdflatex - major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.
2021-08-19 17:29:24,873+0300 INFO  pdflatex - this process (9680) started by 'cmd' with command line: C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe sample.tex
2021-08-19 17:29:24,888+0300 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2021-08-19 17:29:24,999+0300 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2021-08-19 17:29:25,069+0300 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2021-08-19 17:29:26,758+0300 ERROR pdflatex - C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2021-08-19 17:29:26,758+0300 ERROR pdflatex - output:
2021-08-19 17:29:26,758+0300 ERROR pdflatex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2021-08-19 17:29:26,758+0300 FATAL pdflatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-08-19 17:29:26,758+0300 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-08-19 17:29:26,758+0300 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:717
2021-08-19 17:29:26,759+0300 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-08-19 17:29:26,759+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-08-19 17:29:26,759+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-08-19 17:29:26,759+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 717
2021-08-19 17:29:26,765+0300 INFO  pdflatex - this process (9680) finishes with exit code 1
2021-08-19 17:33:47,833+0300 INFO  pdflatex - this process (6796) started by 'cmd' with command line: C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe sample.tex
2021-08-19 17:33:47,852+0300 INFO  pdflatex - this is MiKTeX-PDFTEX 4.8.0 (1.40.23) (MiKTeX 21.8)
2021-08-19 17:33:47,878+0300 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2021-08-19 17:33:47,945+0300 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2021-08-19 17:33:47,945+0300 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2021-08-19 17:33:49,868+0300 ERROR pdflatex - C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2021-08-19 17:33:49,868+0300 ERROR pdflatex - output:
2021-08-19 17:33:49,868+0300 ERROR pdflatex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2021-08-19 17:33:49,868+0300 FATAL pdflatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-08-19 17:33:49,868+0300 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-08-19 17:33:49,869+0300 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:717
2021-08-19 17:33:49,869+0300 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-08-19 17:33:49,869+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2021-08-19 17:33:49,869+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-08-19 17:33:49,869+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 717
2021-08-19 17:33:49,875+0300 INFO  pdflatex - this process (6796) finishes with exit code 1
2021-08-19 17:36:53,994+0300 INFO  pdflatex - this process (6948) started by 'cmd' with command line: pdflatex --version
2021-08-19 17:36:54,001+0300 INFO  pdflatex - this is MiKTeX-PDFTEX 4.8.0 (1.40.23) (MiKTeX 21.8)
2021-08-19 17:36:54,007+0300 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2021-08-19 17:36:54,807+0300 INFO  pdflatex - this process (6948) finishes with exit code 0
```

I tried the same installation on an existing Windows 10 Home machine, and it works fine without asking for a package update in the beginning. I do not know if the Windows version is relevant, I just mention it as an extra info.

Comment: there should be at least one log file in `C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\makefmt\pdflatex`. Show the newest.

Comment: I found a similar path, `C:\Users\theo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\makefmt\pdflatex\2021-08-19-17-33-48.log`. The last lines are:

\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen45


! LaTeX3 Error: File 'UnicodeData.txt' not found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.31012   }
           
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: your are out of luck here. I have seen this error already 2 or 3 times e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/592762/2388, but it was never possible to find out why miktex can't find it.  Check if you have the unicodedata package installed, and then perhaps try at the miktex github.

Comment: By the way: if you run `miktex-kpsewhich UnicodeData.txt`, the file is not found. If you run `miktex-kpsewhich --format=tex UnicodeData.txt`, the file is found.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you, I'll submit an issue at github.

Comment: @ChristianSchenk you are right, actually the first command returns nothing. However, I cannot understand the meaning of them and their difference.

Comment: @Theo the commands show that the file `UnicodeData.txt` exists but cannot be found by LaTeX3. This seems to be very system-dependent.